Change of variables formula for functions with a bounded Jacobian determinant
From the change of variables formula for probability density functions it holds that for $p_H, p_Z$ two pdfs and $g$ a diffeomorphism with $g(x) \sim p_Z$ we have
$$ p_H(x) = p_Z(g(x)) |\det J_g(x)|,$$
where $J_g$ the Jacobian of $g$. If we now consider the set of functions $g$ with a bounded Jacobian determinant, namely $\{ g \ : \ | \det J_g(x)| \leq C \}$ for some $C > 0$, how does this limit the set of distributions $p_H$ that we are capable of approximating?
I assume that there must be some limitation in terms of the ability to obtain a $p_Z$-distributed output from $g$ when bounding the Jacobian determinant. I am grateful for any hint and also literature references, as I find it hard to think of a consequence that bounding the Jacobian determinant might have.
